# Passing arguments to JAR which is required by Java Interpreter

Tags: java

When i execute my **java application** i need to pass arguments which is needed by Java interpreter for Flash image.

for eg. java -sum_arg Demo

Now i want to create JAR file for my application and how can i overcome need of arguments.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass arguments to Java applications packed into `.jar` files just as you can with single `.class` files:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar anArgument
```

If you care about the UI case where a user simply double-clicks the `.jar` file to run your application, then you might want to consider using a real UI (using Swing, for example).

A simple way to get input this way would be with a [`JOptionPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

```
String myInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter something!");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have not any class path dependencies

```
java -jar test.jar "arg1" "arg2"
```

If you have any class-path dependencies

```
java -cp classpath-dependencies -jar test.jar "arg1" "arg2"
```

In swing we can get parameter from command line argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(String arg : args)
        System.out.println(arg);
}
```