# How to execute jar with command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line, ant, jar, executable-jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing arguments to JAR which is required by Java Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536476/passing-arguments-to-jar-which-is-required-by-java-interpreter)

how to provide command line input to a file which is in a jar
I have a jar file hello.jar with some say execute.java file which i want to execute from command line with two arguments;how can i achive this
i have mentioned a executable.java as a main class in a manifest file and using ant 
i have to run this file from ant run with command line arguments

Thanks and Regards
samarth

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this in the command shell:

```
java -cp your-classpath-dependencies-here -jar hello.jar "arg1" "arg2"
```

Do it in Ant with the `<java>` built-in task:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Comment: Or really in most cases just `java -jar jarfile.jar` :p

Comment: Cant i do this with some target of "ANT"

Comment: i want to do this from ant run like this since i have lots of dependency jars