# how to execute jar files with arguments from terminal?

Tags: jar, terminal, arguments, execute

I came up with the following code to calculate the factorial of a given number:

```
import java.lang.*;

import java.math.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
class factorial_1{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException

{

System.out.println("enter a number: ");

String strPhone = "";  
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

strPhone = br.readLine();

BigInteger number = new BigInteger (strPhone);

BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("1");

BigInteger i = new BigInteger("1");

BigInteger step = new BigInteger("1");

final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

final long durationInMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;

for ( ; i.compareTo(number) <= 0; i=i.add(step)){

    fact = fact.multiply(i);

}

System.out.println("execute Long-Running Task took " + durationInMilliseconds + "ms.");

System.out.println("the factorial of "+ number +" is "+ fact);

}

}
```

if you execute the code, it reads a number from the keyboard and then 
prints out its factorial

I exported the code as a .jar file and tried to give the number (10) as input, from the terminal

I did as this post says [How to execute jar with command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777124/how-to-execute-jar-with-command-line-arguments) but nothing happened until I typed again the number

> -----------Terminal-----------
>
> roditis@NiSLab-pc2:~/Desktop$ java -jar import_number.jar 10
>
> enter a number:
>
> 10
>
> execute Long-Running Task took 0ms.
>
> the factorial of 10 is 3628800
>
> -----------Terminal-----------

Im new to linux / programming and I really look forward for your help

Thanks in advance

Roditis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try putting the value in quotes like `roditis@NiSLab-pc2:~/Desktop$ java -jar import_number.jar "10"`

Remember that your main function takes an array of String objects like so `public static void main(String[] args)`.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I see that you are not reading the `args[]` parameter at all. If you provide `"10"` as an argument to your program, then `args[0]` will contain that value. Please check `if(args.length >= 1)` in your case before accessing `args`.

Comment: Michiel Thank you very much for your help :D 
From your EDIT i realized that i have to change the 

BigInteger number = new BigInteger (strPhone);

into

BigInteger number = new BigInteger (args[0]);

and now it works like a charm :D